# How can I add a new line of text between 2 lines using awk/sed? (in a file)

Tags: json, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have the following block of code:

```
{
  "operation_machine": "Ford",
  "operation_steps": [
    "steps/Step_1/01_paint_the_car.json",
    "steps/Step_2/01_drive_the_car.json",
    "steps/Step_2/02_park_the_car.json"
  ]
}
```

I would like to add a new line (step) in the list between line x and y. Say, if I would need to add action number "2" (string=wax_the_car) for step "1" it would look in the end like this:

```
{
  "operation_machine": "Ford",
  "operation_steps": [
    "steps/Step_1/01_paint_the_car.json",
    "steps/Step_1/02_wax_the_car.json",
    "steps/Step_2/01_drive_the_car.json",
    "steps/Step_2/02_park_the_car.json"
  ]
}
```

I have just got into AWK but I think I need to read the book 10 time before I can do this on my own.
I need your help guys/girls.

Comment: Why do you want to edit JSON using text processing tools? Why not use JSON processing tools instead?

Comment: Because this is the environment in which I have to do it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/Step_2\/01/{print ">>> new line here <<<"}1' file
{
  "operation_machine": "Ford",
  "operation_steps": [
    "steps/Step_1/01_paint_the_car.json",
>>> new line here <<<
    "steps/Step_2/01_drive_the_car.json",
    "steps/Step_2/02_park_the_car.json"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this only prints the old version of the block without any newline inserted. :(

Comment: it will only insert the line before the pattern `Step_2/01`. if your data file doesn't have this line it won't print anything extra.  You can replace it with any other unique pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A naive usage of `sed` would be the following:

```
sed -i '/text you know is there/ a the line you want to beneath it' file
```

In your example:

```
sed -i '/paint_the_car/ a "steps/Step_1/02_wax_the_car.json",' file
```

This example needs `GNU sed`.

If you want to autoformat, the `a` isn't really suited, as it is oblivious to the matched line, and you can't really make it conscious.
This works, but isn't as trivial as the first one:

```
sed -i '/paint_the_car/ s_\([ \t]*\).*_&\n\1"steps/Step_1/02_wax_the_car.json",_' file
```

`\(something\)` will match *something* and can later be referenced with `\1`.
`&` will reference the whole string matched in the first part of the substitution command.

Comment: Of course you can write tabs with *ANSI C quoting*, like this `$'word\tword after tabstop'`. However autoformatting is not as trivial as this. For a more complicated answer, see my edited anwer.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use awk you can do the following:

```
awk '/steps\/Step\_1\/01\_paint\_the\_car\.json/{print $0 `RS` "    \"line1\"" RS "    \"line2\"";next}1' input_file
```

**explanation**:

First you match the pattern `'/pattern/'`, then you print the current line `print $0`. With RS (Record Separator, default value new line) you tell to insert a new line and then you add the actual new lines which will be printed because of the `1` at the very end. `next` skip the already printed line.

remember to protect `/` , `_` , `.` which are special characters in the pattern matching `/patter/` of awk.

note also the spaces:

```
"    \"new line1"
 ^^^^
```

To adjust the format. You can also use `\t` : "`\tnew line1`" to auto-format with a tab.

Then you have to save the result of the awk command:

```
awk 'command above' > out_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\#"steps/Step_2/01_drive_the_car\.json"#{p;s##"steps/Step_1/02_wax_the_car.json"#}' file
```

Match the string, print it, replace the string and print the result.

N.B. `\#...#` uses the `#` as the match delimiter (when using the substitute command `s/.../.../` there is no need to quote the first delimiter). Also the empty match uses the last one be default. Lastly, metacharacters in the match should be quoted i.e. `.`,`[` or `]` etc should be `\.`,`\[` or `\]` etc